# Is it possible to update an object defined in a public function from another public function inside a PHP class?

Tags: php

Inside a PHP class I defined an object in a public function and I would like to update that object from another public function in the same class.
Is that possible?

Unfortunately I am not very familiar with classes, but I like to learn.

This is what I have tried:

```
class test {
  public function setObj() {
    $obj1 = (object)[];
    $obj2 = (object)[];
  }

  public function objUpdate() {
    $this->setObj()->obj1->item1 = 'value1';
    $this->setObj()->obj1->item2 = 'value2';

    $this->setObj()->obj2->item3 = 'value3';
    $this->setObj()->obj2->item4 = "value4";

    $obj_merged = (object) array_merge((array) $this->obj1, (array) $this->obj2);
//    $obj_merged = (object) array_merge((array) $obj1, (array) $obj2);
    return $obj_merged;
  }
}

$testobj = new test();
var_dump($testobj->objUpdate());
```

But I got this error:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Attempt to modify property "obj1" on null.

If someone can help me with this problem, I would be very pleased.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your `setObj()` returns nothing yet you are trying to use that nothing

Comment: Variables and thus also objects that are defined within functions or class methods only exist within the function and there only during the execution of the function. These objects can never be changed from the outside either.

Answer (score 0):

#1 the variables in `setObj()` are only in the local scope of the method. You'd have to  declare class properties.

#2 `setObj()` must return `$this` to support method-chaining. Then will `$this->setObj()->obj1->item3 = 'value3';` work

```
class test {
    protected $obj1;
    protected $obj2;
    
    public function setObj() {
        $this->obj1 = (object)[];
        $this->obj2 = (object)[];

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Didn't copy `objUpdate()`, I think it'll work if you copy it in..

Comment: I tried your example and copied de rest of my code in. Now I don't get no error, but I get this result: object(stdClass)#4 (1) {
  ["item4"]=> string(6) "value4"
} - so the values get overwritten each time. How can I solve that?

Comment: Well, after all it turns out  I must deal with static functions instead.  This is what I tried now:  class test {  
  public $obj1;  
  public $obj2;  

  public static function setObj() {  
    $obj1 = (object)[];  
    $obj2 = (object)[];  
  }  

  public static function objUpdate() {  
    self::setObj()->obj1->item1 = 'value1'; // Attempt to modify property "obj1" on null  
    self::setObj(obj1)->item2 = 'value2'; // Undefined constant "obj1"  
    self::setObj($obj1)->item3 = 'value3'; // Undefined variable $obj1  
  }  
}  
How can I update objects from another function.